# How can I customize the comment styles that come with Atom One Dark theme?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm new to Atom and I was wondering if we could customize the comment styles that come with the One Dark Syntax Theme via the `style.less` `(Atom > Stylesheet...)` file. I looked up the source code for the theme and in the `language.less` file I found this:

```
.comment {
color: @mono-3;
font-style: italic;

.markup.link {
color: @mono-3;
  }
}
```

Specifically, I would like to change to `font-style` to `normal` but I can't seem to find a way, please help. Thanks.

Comment: In Notepad++, all I have to do is go to Settings > Style Configurator > Language > COMMENTLINE > Pick a color > Save.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't use `atom-text-editor::shadow` any more

[image]

You should now use

```
atom-text-editor.editor .syntax--comment {
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Update]

Atom has changed and the accepted answer is now the one you should use!

[Old Answer]

The elements you're trying to target are inside the text editor element's shadow DOM; try

```css
atom-text-editor::shadow .comment {
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind telling me how I can arrive at this answer?

Comment: Some of it requires being familiar with the shadow DOM and how to style it. But there's a quick example under "Style Tweaks" in the [Atom Flight Manual customization page](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/).

Comment: Atom rules has been updated, and this one in particular has been replaced.
`atom-text-editor::shadow .comment` -> `atom-text-editor.editor .syntax--comment`

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, you would want to change your example to

```
.editor, atom-text-editor::shadow {
  .comment {
    font-style: normal;
  }
}
```